# Unit testing a method that gets called on certain event

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, ios6

Let me first describe the scenario. User first logs in to facebook. On completion, a method is called and in that method I call another method named `myMethod`. `myMethod` gets user details from facebook. I want to test that all user details are fetched and are not nil.

Main point is that testing a method `myMethod` required facebook login. Without logging in this method will not save anything and no point in testing it.

Is there any way to test it? Even I am not sure whether I should test it.

I use `GHUnit` for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably the easiest way to do it is to save the JSON response from Facebook and save it.  This saved JSON data will tell you whether your fetch is working or not, then you can feed that response to myMethod and test whether fetched details are properly processed.

EDIT: If you're using FBSession as an input to myMethod, then just use FBTestSession.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBTestSession
Dont't forget to create test user first.

Comment: `myMethod` takes as an argument `FBSession`.